# How to pay a large invoice from a company in a European country from the US

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer, payment, europe

Is a wire transfer the only way? I'm not near my normal bank who requires you to be in person to wire money so I'd prefer another option if it exists

Comment: The simple answer is ofx.com (and competitors) exists for this very purpose, they process gazillions a day, and there's no other practical solution.  It's incredibly easy once you establish an account.

Comment: Actually ofx (/competitors) is an AMAZING example of a company making a STAGGERING amount of money by observing a problem *("sending money internationally from the USA is as laughably. risibly, ridiculously hilarious as the best Jim Carrey movie")* and then offering a solution.  Smart stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer is to **simply use ofx.com** (or a competitor such as transferwise.com)

Sending a "wire" is laughable in the US. Don't even bother.

(Don't even mention that the exchange rate you'll get is crap.)

**It's a nuisance to set up an account** at ofx or the others, but once it is in place, **everything is dead easy, one click**.

Source, we do this dozens of times a month. (And fwiw I owned various money-transfer related companies, though mainly drunk at the time. But still.)

Comment: This worked great, I didn't find the account setup to be onerous at all and I much prefer it to having to physically go to my bank to send a wire even if I were in the same town.

Comment: @brezotom - interesting, perhaps they have improved it. Great!  Do you mind if I ask if you went with transferwise, ofx, etc ?

Comment: I went with OTX. It took a few minutes to fill out the info they needed, they called me to do a manual step before I finished the form. Then I connected my bank by just entering my details and authorizing otx.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the only way.

Most banks will write you an [international bank draft](https://www.nbc.ca/personal/advice/banking/what-is-a-bank-draft.html) (like a cashier check but in in any currency), payable to anybody. They might mail it direct to the company, or mail it to you so you can mail it to them. This is usually the cheapest way to send large amounts.

If it's a large company they may have a US branch or a US dollar bank account, and thus take a check in US$.

If your invoice is less than $10,000 you can use an [International Money Order](https://www.americanexpress.com/us/foreign-exchange/articles/international-money-orders/).

Here is [an overview of ways to send money abroad](https://www.mybanktracker.com/news/sending-money-abroad#Bank).

Comment: Sorry - I did put in a downvote here since, as far as I know, every single point is wrong!  Heh! :)  Again did you realize OP is in US ?

Comment: If that's the case then the US bank system is utterly terrible. I've done all of the above in many countries, including Canada, and since Canadian banks are usually similar to the US I have presumed US banks will do it.

Comment: DJ - (1) yes, the US bank system is utterly, utterly, utterly terrible  (2) Canada banks are pretty good {indeed, I have used accounts there a number of times for that very reason}  (3) "Canadian banks are usually similar to the US" that is incredibly, totally, incorrect  (4) "presumed US banks will do it"  As I say, I'm afraid I did downvote (I never bother voting) since, well, **every single point in your answer is entirely and totally wrong**.  Heh!  :) :)  Sorry ...

Comment: I'm finding references that say these are actually possible. I may have got the name wrong.

Comment: I'm really sorry man.  Your entire answer (including the new version) is unfortunately incredibly "wrong".  (The two web pages linked are totally hopeless.)  {And the two points in your coimment are absolutely incorrect :) )  Knowing you I'm surprised you'd put in an answer you (I guess) have no experience with?!  Next time there's a very specific Canada question about a topic of which I have never done, I will answer ;-) I'll leave it at that.  Hopefully no-one is actual misled here.  Overwhelmingly, 999 times out of 1000, when you do what it says in the title, you just use ofx/etc.

Comment: (or, if it's the "only time you'll ever do it" you go through the almost unbelievable pain/expense of "sending a wire from the US!" heh!)

Comment: Some US banks do issue foreign drafts: [1](https://www.columbiabank.com/business-banking/international-banking/foreign-drafts) [2](https://www.coastcapitalsavings.com/help/business-banking/drafts)